# Using tensor calculus to derive a simple regression

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

This is probably a very simple question for someone with some tensor calculus background, sorry in advance if that's not an interesting question!

I am trying to understand very basic tensor calculus so I apply it on a problem for which there is actually a simple answer to which I can relate.

Let's say that we have a dataset, which consists of $n$ pairs $(x_i, y_i)$, for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and we want to do a simple linear regression (least square minimization) of the form $y \sim ax+b$. The simplest approach is to create a matrix $X$ that contains 2 columns, one with all $1$'s and one with the components of $x_i$. With this matrix and the vector $c = [a, b]$, we can easily show that the solution to the least square minimization problem is the solution of:
$$(X^TX)c = X^TY$$

Now, let's instead try to think in terms of tensor calculus. My idea here is to consider that $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are vectors in the Euclidian space $\mathbb{R}^n$. We create a 2D manifold $M$ in that space that is generated by $\vec{1}$ and $\vec{x}$, where $\vec{1}$ is a unit vector with all components equal to 1. The minimizer that we are looking for should be simply the projection of $\vec{y}$ on that manifold $M$, in some coordinates related to $M$.

The metric tensor $g_{ij}$ in that manifold is constant but not generally orthogonal. If we consider that $\vec{e}_1 = \vec{1}$ and $\vec{e}_2 = \vec{x}$ then the metric tensor is:

$$g_{ij} = \vec{e}_i \cdot \vec{e}_j$$

We can easily show that this is exactly like $X^TX$ in the matrix formulation above.

As the metric tensor in $M$ is constant, we know that $M$ is a plane so the projection on the plane should be straightforward to perform in an Euclidian space. In general, if we have a curved manifold then I expect that we need to be more careful about this projection but this is outside of the scope of my question today!

Now, I am struggling to understand how we manage to formalize the rest of the problem. My intuition is that there is a way to link directly $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{y}$ but I struggle to write it down. For example, we could think that the coordinates $c_i$ of the contravariant form of the solution $\vec{c}$ are actually the projection of $y$ on some basis but I don't see how to. If we're allowed to write it:
$$c_i = g_{ij} c^j = \mathrm{proj}(\vec{y})_i$$

The natural choice for this projection seems to me to to take the scalar product of $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{e}^i$ but I don't see how I will balance the indices on both sides of the equation...

Comment: One of the problems you have is that we’re talking about a system of linear equations $Ac=b$, so $A$ is a linear map (a tensor of type (1,1)), whereas your $g_{ij}$ is a tensor of type (2,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track and almost at the finish line.

Let
$$c_i=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \vec{x}\cdot \vec{y},\, \vec{1}\cdot \vec{y}\\
\end{array}
\right),\quad g_{hk}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \vec{x}\cdot\vec{x} & \vec{x}\cdot\vec{1} \\
 \vec{1}\cdot\vec{x} & \vec{1}\cdot\vec{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
And let $g^{jl}$ be the inverse of $g_{hk}$ (this is the usual $g^{jl}g_{jk}=\delta^l_k$).

As you explained in your post the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf{y}$ onto the subspace spanned by the columns of $X$, is $\mathbf{y}'=Xc$ where $c^j$ satisfies $c_i=g_{ij}c^j$ so all we have to do is to "raise" the index of $c_i$

$$c^l=g^{jl}c_j=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a \\
 b\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

---

Lets study a basic example. Find the  linear least square fit ($y=ax+b$) of the three data points $(x_i,y_i)=(-1,1),\,(1,2),\,(2,3)$. We are using the basis vectors
$\vec{x}=(-1,1,2),\,\vec{1}=(1,1,1)$. Finally we use the projection $c_i=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \vec{x}\cdot \vec{y},\, \vec{1}\cdot \vec{y}\\
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
 7,\, 6\\
\end{array}\right)$ and the Gramian and its inverse

$$g_{hk}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 6 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\quad g^{jl}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{3}{14} & -\frac{1}{7} \\
 -\frac{1}{7} & \frac{3}{7} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now all we have to do is to contract $g^{jl}$ with $c_j$ (ie raising the index)

$$c^l=g^{jl}c_j=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{9}{14} \\
 \frac{11}{7}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

So the best fit in the least-squares sense is the line $y=\frac{9}{14}x+\frac{11}{7} $

Comment: I knew that I was close but I couldn't visualise that the solution was so simple! I tried to understand what is a tensor and a metric in a few different ways but I think that this approach (using a non-orthogonal but constant basis) is probably the most intuitive from my point of view. One thing that I started to visualize thinking about this problem is how the basis and the dual basis work with each other. I can't upvote your answer though as I don't have enough reputation yet... sorry.